# sql: words match separately, find out the spelling is partly different

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Does anyone have a idea to matches below 2 situation?

Data:

```
ID| NAMES
1 | ASHRA MUHAMMAD YUSU
2 | ASHRAF MUHAMMAD YUSUF
3 | YUSUF UTHMAN ABD
```

=====================

I'm using SqlServer2008, and 
There are 2 user requirements:
(1) Find out the spelling is partly different
For example: the user enters "ASHRA YUSU", the following is my expected result:

```
ID| NAMES
2 | ASHRAF MUHAMMAD YUSUF
```

(2) Find out the name is exactly the same, allow the order is different
For example: the user enters "ASHRA YUSU", the following is my expected result:

```
ID| NAMES
1 | ASHRA MUHAMMAD YUSU
```

Comment: In your first case you don't want to include exactly same result?

Comment: I did this many years ago.  The way to do is doing a table-valued function, that split in space.  It returns 1 row = 1 word.  You then only need to to a regular join.

Comment: Are all the names 3 parts ?

Comment: hi, tejash patel , for 1st case , "exactly same" is not the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] 
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX) 
) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)

    END 
    RETURN 
END   

go

;with tmp as (select <table>.id, splitdata
        from <table> cross apply dbo.fnSplitString(<table>.name, ' '))
, tmp2 as (select distinct <table>.id, count(*) cnt
        from dbo.fnSplitString(<search string>, ' ') tmp2
        inner join tmp on tmp.splitdata = tmp2.splitData
        group by tmp.id)
  select <table>.*, cnt from <table> inner join tmp2 on <table>.Id = tmp2.Id;
```

Comment: I wait for the day, where people stop posting string splitters with `WHILE` or any other kind of procedural loops...

Comment: Shnugo, what is your solution?

Comment: Dan, with SQL-Server 2017+ there is `STRING_SPLIT()` (or even better `OPENJSON()`). With former versions there are several approaches using a transformation to XML, recursive CTEs or tally/number tables. There are many answers on SO covering this, [a good overview is this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10914576/5089204). Just ignore all approaches with `WHILE`, *multi-statement UDF* or scalar functions... And you might read this [great article serie by Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)